# Unable to prevent keypresses from unsuspending laptop

Tags: keyboard, suspend, acpi

It appears that due to the poor build of my laptop, keys sometimes get pressed in my backpack, even though the lid is closed. This causes it to silently resume from sleep, then overheat and drain the battery.

I've been trying to turn keypress wakeups off, but unsuccessfully so.

Before closing the lid, I've disabled all device wakeups:

```
$ cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled
EHC1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
XHC       S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:01:00.0
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
LID0      S3    *disabled
PWRB      S4    *disabled
```

After waking it up by pressing some key (doing so by slightly opening the lid, just enough to reach a key), it seems PXSX has somehow enabled itself for wakeup:

```
stefan@stefan-PC ~> cat /proc/acpi/wakeup
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
P0P1      S4    *disabled
EHC1      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1d.0
XHC       S3    *disabled  pci:0000:00:14.0
HDEF      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1b.0
RP03      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.0
PXSX      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:01:00.0
RP04      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.3
PXSX      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:02:00.0
RP05      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:00:1c.4
PEGP      S4    *disabled  pci:0000:03:00.0
PEG0      S4    *disabled
PEGP      S4    *disabled
PEG1      S4    *disabled
PEG2      S4    *disabled
LID0      S3    *disabled
PWRB      S4    *disabled
```

Not sure what causes this or how to stop it. /var/log/dmesg, /var/log/pm-suspend.log, /var/log/syslog show absolutely no information about the wakeup reason or about PXSX (I assume PXSX is the keyboard, not sure though).
Looking at /usr/lib/pm-utils and /etc/pm/sleep.d, there seem to be no hooks which would enable PXSX.

Could you suggest a way of debugging and fixing this issue? Thanks!

```
$ uname -a
Linux x 3.13.0-49-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Fri Apr 10 20:11:33 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: is it a dell? I think its [wifi-catcher](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080531063321AA9mNv6). if not, it might be a more generic code for your WiFi on/off switch. in either case you should be able to disable it in the firmware.

Comment: the wake up is caused by keypresses, i'm not sure how wi-fi is related?

Comment: the WiFi switch is what I'm talking about. is it on the side of the laptop?